# req.user is undefined and req.isAuthenticated() is not a function

Tags: node.js, passport.js, express-session

I am using passport express-session for authentication, Used local-strategy.

deserializeUser function by passport gets the user, but callback function (done used by me) either doesnot set in req.user or unset before getting control to setUserAuthentication (where set res.local.user as req.user).

There were many questions having similar issue, what I understood was to keep middleware in right sequence, which looks right to me as said, keeping route after session ,passport.initialize(), and passport.session()

server code

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('./assets'));
app.use(layout);
app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');
app.set('views','./views');
app.set('layout','./layouts');
app.use(session({
    name : 'user_key',
    secret : 'anything',
    saveUninitialized : false,
    resave : false,
    
    cookie : {
        maxAge : (1000*60*100)
    }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(passport.setUserAuthentication);
app.use('/' , require('./routes'));
```

In congig/pasport-local-strategy.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    {
        usernameField : 'email'
    },
    function(email , password , done){
    
        User.findOne({email : email},function(err , user){
            if(err){
                console.log('error in finding user');
                return done(err);
            }
            if(!user || user.password != password){
                console.log('invalid credentials');
                return done(null,false);
            }
            return done(null,user);
            
        })
    }
))

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
    done(null,user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
    // console.log(id);
    User.findById(id,(err,user)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log('error in finding user');
            return done(err);
        }
       return done(null,user);

    })
});

passport.checkAuthentication = function(res,req,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
       return  next();
    }
    else res.redirect('/users/sign-in');
}
passport.setUserAuthentication = function(res,req,next){
   
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.locals.user = req.user;
    }
    next();
}

module.exports = passport;
```

Directory structure

```
config / passport-lcal-starategy
controller/user_handler.js
routes/user.js
index.js(server)
```

Comment: Seems like you inverted the params order, I think it should be `function(req, res, next){`

Comment: yeah!, you are right, it feels very silly now.

Comment: yes that worked just fine, I spent like 3 hours looking other different issue there can be, to find what i did was just so silly.